# How to put 2 headings on same line (next to each other)?

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

Can someone help me to put ''Author:'' on the same line as ''Supervisor:''?

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \large
{\bf Author:}\\
aaa\textsc{bbb} % My name
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \large
{\bf Supervisors:} \\
ccc \textsc{ddd} \\% Name 1
eee \textsc{fff} \\% Name 2
\end{flushright}
```

Comment: Use `[t]` for the `minipage`s: `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}...\end{minipage}`, or use one `tabular` environment for the whole construct. By the way, you should use `\bfseries` and not `\bf`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

With a little more work, you can get a reusable structure, that makes it easier to input your data.

The `namedata` environment takes as first optional argument the global width (default `.8\textwidth`) and as mandatory argument the author's name. The body of the environment consists of the supervisors' names. I show three examples with different width.

An overall `tabular*` environment contains two top aligned `tabular` environments. It's easy to change the inner alignments; for instance I'd prefer left alignment for the supervisors' names (just change the second `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}` in order to see the effect).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\newenvironment{namedata}[2][.8\textwidth]
 {\centering
  \begin{tabular*}{#1}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lr@{}}%
  \namedataauthor{#2} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
    \bfseries Supervisors: \\}
 {\end{tabular}\end{tabular*}\par}
\newcommand{\namedataauthor}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
  \bfseries Author: \\
  #1
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}


\begin{namedata}{My \textsc{Name}}
Super Visor\\
Excellent Visor\\
Extraordinary Visor
\end{namedata}

\bigskip

\begin{namedata}[.6\textwidth]{My \textsc{Name}}
Super Visor\\
Excellent Visor\\
Extraordinary Visor
\end{namedata}

\bigskip

\begin{namedata}[\textwidth]{My \textsc{Name}}
Super Visor\\
Excellent Visor\\
Extraordinary Visor
\end{namedata}
\end{document}
```

[image]